# On Google Analytics 4, can I create Custom Dimensions & Metris at the account level?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, metrics, custom-dimensions, google-analytics-4

I have an account with 3 properties. They all will use the same custom dimensions & custom metrics.

Can I set those at the account level? Or will I have to replicate the same settings for each one of the properties?

[image]